# Find the probability density function of $Y=lnX$

Tags: self-study, descriptive-statistics

Suppose $X$ is a continuous random variable with probability density function $f(x)=\dfrac{\theta}{x^{\theta + 1}}$ for $x\geq1$ and $\theta > 0$

So $h^{-1}(Y)=e^y$
then $f_y(y) = f_x(e^y)|\dfrac{d(e^y)}{dy}|$

Which I think results in $f_y(y)=\dfrac{\theta}{e^{y\theta}}$ for $0<y$

Is this correct? And if it is, should this result in a $E(X)=\infty$

Comment: Didn't you miss the multiplication by the derivative? $$\left|\frac{d(e^y)}{dy}\right|=\left|e^y\right|=e^y,$$ and $$f_X(e^y)=\frac{\theta}{e^{y(\theta+1)}},$$ therefore $$f_Y(y)=\frac{\theta}{e^{y(\theta+1)}}e^y=\frac{\theta}{e^{y\theta}}.$$

Comment: If $f_Y(y)= \theta e^{-\theta y}$ for $y \gt 0$ then this is an exponential distribution with $E[Y]=\dfrac1\theta$

Answer (score 1):

**You get an exponential random variable with rate parameter $\theta$.**  An easy and intuitive way to do this (which does not require you to remember a conversion formula) is by using direct conversion of the distribution function.  For  $y > 0$ you have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned} 
F_Y(y) \equiv \mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant y) &= \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant \exp (y)) \\
&= \int\limits_1^{\exp (y)} \theta x^{-(\theta +1)} dx \\
&= \left[ - x^{-\theta} \right]_{x = 1}^{x = \exp (y)} \\
&= 1 - \exp (y)^{-\theta} \\
&= 1 - \exp (-\theta y).
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

This is the distribution function of an exponential random variable.  The corresponding density function is $f_Y(y) = \theta \exp(-\theta y)$ and the expected value is $\mathbb{E}(Y) = 1/ \theta$.

Comment: Whenever I am trying to find the distribution of a transformed random variable, I always start by looking at the CDFs instead of the PDFs.  That way you don't need to remember any conversion formula - it is much more directly intuitive.